# Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express консольное приложение

Tags: visual-studio-2010

В Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express создаю консольное приложение, которое выводит в консоль данные, потом убираю старый код, пишу новый - а при Сtrl+F5 в консоли выводится то, что выводил прежний код. Как это исправить?

Comment: Если я запускаю отладку через F5, то работает текущий код, а если Сtrl+F5, то старый.

Comment: Я, конечно не мастер в VS, но может быть у вас на F5 влючается компилятор с дебаггером, а на Ctrl+F5 только дебаггер?

Comment: А как это выяснить?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 - запуск без дебага. Ну, хрен его знает, возможно он и не пересобирает при этом. А зачем вам Ctrl+F5, если оно и без контрола прекрасно работает? Сборка проекта отдельное действие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F5 - запуск с отладкой.

ctrl+f5 - запуск кода без отладки. Всё у вас правильно работает.
билдуйте с помощью f6 и будет вам счастье.

Comment: ну у меня как было - я сначала запускаю F5 - работает только что набранный код, запускаю Ctrl+F5 - почему-то работает тот код, который был раньше написан и который уже удален. но потом вроде комп одумался и всё нормально заработало.